# Change the font in the R gui

Tags: r, user-interface

Suddenly, today, the font that R uses in its gui window looks like this:

[image]

How can I get it to look nice again?

---

Note:

I do *not* want to specify fonts in plots.

I'm on a Mac under OS 10.9.5 using R 3.0.2.

Comment: Are you using Rstudio?

Comment: @DavidArenburg No. Plain R (on a Mac).

Comment: That could potentially happen if you accessed your Mac remotely. Did you try to close and reopen? Either way, you can edit your interface by going `Edit -> GUI preferences...`

Comment: Yes, I closed and reopened. Even rebooted the computer. I don't seem to have `Edit > GUI preferences`...

Comment: What R version are you using? I don't use Mac, so it could be potentially Mac related problem

Comment: I use R 3.0.2, I'll try updating.

Comment: The console font is hardcoded into the R.app's plist. You can follow [these instructions](http://blog.thekensta.com/2012/04/change-default-font-in-rapp-on-mac-os-x.html) to modify it, but there's a (small) chance it'll get overwritten on a new R install. You can also try deleting that plist file and let R create a new one to see if that helps.

Comment: @hrbrmstr That is great advice. I'm good at the moment (see my answer below), but if ever that problem returns, I'll try both your tips. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I don't know what the problem was, but updating R to the most recent version turned on antialiasing again:

> [image]

As David Arenburg noted in a comment above, the problem might have been caused by remote access: I accessed this laptop from my desktop iMac yesterday to do a backup. Also I'm currently building fonts with FontForge, and the problem might be related to this (unfinished fonts lying around somewhere).

Anyway, the new installation did it (for the moment). If anyone knows how to analyse and solve this problem without installing, please post an answer.

Comment: Sadly, it's going to be hard to "break" the console font deliberately.  You might try copypasting formatted text from, e.g. a Word doc to see if that does it; in which case possibly using the Rgui submenu Font/copy-paste format will help (tho other comments suggest not).